# Exract model object data from .dgn file with Forge Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We've had good luck importing, converting, and extracting meta data from .rvt files using the following steps:

1. Uploading files in chunks to an OSS bucket using resumable endpoint

   - PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable
2. Kicking off a new job to convert the file to SVF

   - POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
   - { "input": { "urn": ":urn" }, "output": {"formats": [ { "type": "svf", "views": ["2d", "3d"] } ] } }
3. Validating the job completed successfully completed

   - GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest
4. Get the GUID for the 3D view

   - GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata
5. Check that the metadata call doesn't returns 200 not 202

   - GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid

When running a .dgn (Bentley) file through this process, it gets through steps 1-4 OK, and even loads and displays metadata in the viewer. But, the call in step 5 will never return 200OK or and metadata.

Anyone had any luck working with non Autodesk file types?

Comment: Hi @Ben, can I know you are testing with 2D or 3D DGN? if 2D, sorry 
getting metadata is not yet doable for 2D documents. This has been logged as a wish and will be implemented by the development team. the other post tells in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956703/how-do-i-get-metadata-from-a-2d-dwg-file-using-forge-autodesk-apis

Comment: I tested with a 3D DGN, the metadata works well. This is a snapshot in Navisworks and Postman (with Forge endpoint) . https://ibb.co/iLsKfR

Comment: Thanks! I am working with a 3D dgn, it's actually just an sample I downloaded to test. http://www.q-cad.com/samples/microstation-3d/microstation-3d-samples/ . I suppose it's possible there isn't data to extract, but I find that hard to believe because I get properties in the viewer. And if there was an error, I would expect the metadata call to fail rather than return 202 forever

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with this specific DGN file. I agreed with you that if there is any error to extract the metadata, the model structure or property should not work well in Forge Viewer. I logged the issue as internal ticket : DERI-4718 . Please make a note for inquiry in the future. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: just an update: the root issue has been addressed by our engineer team.

Comment: Thanks Xiaodong! Any update on when this will be released?

Comment: Hi @Ben, sorry I missed your comments. We have not an exact time table when the fix would be available. While we will inform when it is released. Thank you for your patience!